# Redirect User to Website After Sign-Up

Tags: foursquare

I'm integrating Foursquare into an app I work on, and everything works fine with the user flow. It successfully redirects to Foursquare, asks the user for permission, then returns to the website successfully. However, I ran into a bit of an edge case where if the user has not already joined Foursquare, it sends them to the permission page as expected with a link to sign up for Foursquare. However, once they sign up it looks like it never actually takes them back to the permission page, is there a way to do that that I am missing? I couldn't really find anything on Google. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating to Foursquare by an App can done either directly taking the viewer into app or providing the details of login however integrating will be denied by Social website like foursquare.

Comment: I guess I was talking about a situation where, in the first part of the OAuth dance when a user is attempting to retrieve a code, if they are not a registered Foursquare user it gives them to option to sign up. After sign up I'd like to have Foursquare return to the code page to ask permission for my Foursquare application to access their account. Is this possible?